# Design of Compound Elliptical Concentrator and Compound Parabolic Concentrator

Tags: optics, solar-energy, photovoltaics

What is the process in design a Compound Elliptical Concentrator and Compound Parabolic Concentrator if I wanted to achieve 100% optimal concentration ? Let's assume random numbers of: A light source being 14 meters wide, the aperture is 4 meters wide and the distance between them being 12 meters.

I was doing random searches on solar energy and came across solar concentrators which I've never heard of before, but saw you can design them based on knowing information above. I can't find anything easy enough to understand so a newbie like me can follow clearly.

For example, for the CPC. The equation is for the maximum concentration: $$C=\frac{1}{sin^2(\theta)}$$

If I wanted a 100% concenctration would have a 1 (100%) in place of the C then solve for the theta to get the half acceptance angle ? Would I go backwards from this and adjust the base of the concetrator to have an aperture of 4 meters and a base of whatever gives me an angle of theta?

Here is an image of what I meant (found randomly online with no explanation): [image]

Answer (score 1):

Per the [non-imaging optics wiki](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonimaging_optics), C is the "ratio of input and output aperture areas". It is not efficiency like it is in some other equations.

So putting a 45 degree half angle into the equation gives C = 2. This means that if the input area is 1m^2 then the output will be 0.5m^2. A solar radiation intensity would increase from say 1000w/m^2 to 2000w/m^2.

At a 30 degree half angle the equation gives C = 4. So solar radiaton could be increased to 4000w/m^2. This would be more favorable in a solar heating application but the trade off is the smaller acceptance angle.

At a 90 degree half angle (light from 180 degrees) the equation gives C = 1 meaning no concentration is possible.